# Set method to be defined after instantiation of object

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

How do you define a method of an object that can be set after the object is instantiated, yet, called from inner code within the object when an event has occurred?

For instance, I have a constructor like so:

```
function ExampleObject(){
    if(!(this instanceof ExampleObject)){
        throw "Error not called using the new keyword";
    }
    this.functionToCall; //set a function that can be defined later
    function init(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("get", location, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(typeof this.functionToCall !== "undefined"){//problem with use of "this" here?
                //...execute code...
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
     }
     init();
}
```

And, then, I create an instance of this Object and set the function:

```
var example = new ExampleObject();
example.functionToCall = function(){/*some code*/};
```

However, it never reaches the code within the if statement seeing if the function has been defined (`if(typeof this.functionToCall !== "undefined")`). So, it seems my approach may not be the correct way to do this. Is there another approach to achieve this? If so, why is it that my approach will not work?

Comment: You're doing the `typeof` test in the constructor, not when the event has occurred. You need to put that in another function that's triggered by the event.

Comment: Please elaborate. Why would it matter if the typeof test be in the constructor or in another function? If I'm using the `this` keyword it should be accessing the same objects property.

Comment: And to be honest, this is only an example. My true code does have the condition within another function. I used the comment line `//... event has occurred` to attempt to illustrate this.

Comment: @AndroidStudent: Yes, but at different times: Before vs after you did assign the actual function.

Comment: What matters is WHEN you're doing this. You're doing it when you create the object, so it will always be before you assign the property.

Comment: Please show the true code then.

Comment: Okay so I understand what you mean about when the condition is called matters. I'll edit my code to show my true code to hopefully better illustrate my dillemna.

Comment: Maybe you should simply *pass* that dynamic function as an *argument* to the constructor; instead of modifying instances thereafter.

Comment: Actually, I believe my problem has to do with the use of the `this` keyword. Since I call the condition within an event function within an init function in the constructor. I'll add the code to show...

Comment: Would assigning `this` to a variable solve my issue? And would that be a "proper" approach? Such as: `var that = this;`

Answer (score 0):

So, my approach was okay. My problem had to do with the scope. First, as pointed out in the comments, where you call the condition (`if(typeof this.onmessage !== "undefined")`) does matter. If it is called in the constructor, then `this.onmessage` would not have been defined yet. Therefore, it must be called within an event function, which is where my problem arose.

In my event function, I was calling the "typeof condition" using the `this` keyword. Here, `this` refers to the object calling of the event function (in my case "xhr") and not the instance of the object (ExampleObject) defined by the constructor. To solve this, I simply placed a variable in the constructor function that refers to that instance of `this`:

```
var that = this;
```

Then, I can use this variable within inner functions with different scopes to refer to the ExampleObject instance.